# Overriding method with selector '***' has incompatible type '****' parse

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse. I am trying to query a list of the object in the database. I am using swift programming language. I think the reason cause this error is because obj-c and swift bridge. Can anyone help me ?
Here is my code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
```

Only the first line has error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT! It has to be like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

For some code backward compatibility reasons you can use and the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
```

Just change the "!" signs with "?". I'm using Xcode 6 GM seed. There are some changes in UITableViewDataSource. Iwas geting the same error, but changing it like this work for me ...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove ! after UITableView, NSIndexPath and UITableViewCell as "protocol UITableViewDataSource" is having below signature:

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -UITableViewCell

Христо Атанасов answer too worked for me.