# Overriding method with selector has incompatible type - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Overriding `UITableViewDelegate`'s `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is causing the following compile error:

> Overriding method with selector 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' has incompatible type '(UITableView!, NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!'

The current implementation of the override function is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdent", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

What is causing the error and how can it be fixed?

Comment: try deleting just "override".  If that does not work, please post your entire class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `implicit optional type`.Check in `UITableViewDataSource` there is no optional for `tableView`,`indexPath`.Also remove `override` as you implementing the `protocol` methods you do not need to write `override`

Replace with below method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    //the error is on the line oboe... Overriding method with selector 'tableView:cellforRowAtIndexPath:'has incompatible type '(TableView, NSIndexpath) -. UITableViewCell!'
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdent", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

This may help:
[Overriding method with selector '***' has incompatible type '****' parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756637/overriding-method-with-selector-has-incompatible-type-parse)